# .NET MVC /Javascript escape single quotes from dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, string, quote

I get some dynamic HTML from a server, that i want to put in an iframe. This works:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.write('@Html.Raw(Data)');
```

The problem is that the Data (the HTML that i recieve) may contain " and ' which will conflict with my 's surrounding the html-data. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this myself.
I used  `@Html.JavaScriptStringEncode`
:)

Answer (score 4):

A reliable way to encode values in JavaScript in a Razor view is to use `Json.Encode()`:

```
document.getElementById('iframe')
    .contentWindow.document.write(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Data)));
```

Note that there are no `'` around the value because `Json.Encode()` creates a valid JavaScript literal.

Comment: That looks like the best solution to me, it's more elegant that JavaScriptStringEncode which requires adding js quotes. However, why would I need the Html.Raw() ? Can't I just use @Json.Encode ? EDIT : Ok it seems like you need toeh Html.Raw to prevent automatic HTML character encoding.